# Find overlap range on multiple regions

Tags: c, real-time

I have this question I'm struggling with,

I have a machine, tasks are entering the machine one after the other.

Each task has a task Id, starting number and number of units it requests.

For each task I need to check if the range of the task [start number, start number + request units] overlaps one of the previous tasks ranges, if it does, it will not be executed.

There are 32 tasks Id, the machine can't hold the same task Id at the same time (If task Id 2 is in the machine, it must be executed before entering the machine again, with different parameters maybe)

The basic idea is to hold a control block with the ranges of all the tasks which are in the machine (up to 32) and to scan this structure for each new task, however, not best idea for performance.

Any idea guys?

This is taken from a real world product development, I simplified it this model due. Also I need to write the solution in C so I can't have any complex mathematical theories :)

Comment: You have not defined the machine well enough, such as the range of numbers, and you do not say what happens when a new task cannot be processed. Are all new requests held up at that point or should they be put in a holding queue, while other new requests are processed? It could be quite complicated, since new requests might continually block one in the holding queue. For example, if a running task is processing units 1-4, and a new task for units 3-6 is queued, and then a new task arrives to process units 5-8, that could be permitted but the task held in the queue is still blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Create a task control block structure (TCB_t) to hold the parameters and info about the task.  Create an array of TCB_t * currentTasks[32] = {0} and initialize the pointers to null.  In your addTask(...) routine check if currentTasks[newTaskID] == NULL and if it is allocate a new TCB_t and assign it there.  You can process tasks from the currentTasks list, free them when they're done and set it back to NULL.  Since there are only 32 tasks you can use a direct hash function mapping the TCB_t directly to an entry in the currentTasks array.
You need to also keep a separate list of regions, you could insert each region into a sorted linked list to make it easier to determine if the task to add has overlap with some other task.

Comment: I still need to scan the list of entries for each new task, no?

Comment: Do you know anything in advance about the startNumber or requestUnits?

Comment: No, these parameters can be anything